# WikiEditor toolbar not showing in MediaWiki 1.23 or 1.24

Tags: editor, mediawiki, wysiwyg, wiki

When I edit a page in my wiki, the WikiEditor toolbar doesn't show.

The version of MediaWiki that I use is version 1.23.2 and I am using the latest version of WikiEditor.

This is the code that I used at the bottom of `LocalSettings.php`

```
require_once "$IP/extensions/WikiEditor/WikiEditor.php";

# Enables use of WikiEditor by default but still allow users to disable it in preferences
$wgDefaultUserOptions['usebetatoolbar'] = 1;
$wgDefaultUserOptions['usebetatoolbar-cgd'] = 1;

# Displays the Preview and Changes tabs
$wgDefaultUserOptions['wikieditor-preview'] = 1;
# Displays the Publish and Cancel buttons on the top right side
$wgDefaultUserOptions['wikieditor-publish'] = 1;
```

I am just using the default Vector theme, I haven't changed anything  yet.

Comment: Also asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25189491/wikieditor-toolbar-is-missing?rq=1

Comment: I am not using any custom themes.

Comment: Disable all the others extensions and try again.

Comment: This could be because WikiEditor tries to call the deprecated function mw.loader.version: https://bugzilla.wikimedia.org/show_bug.cgi?id=63762

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I'm  using MediaWiki 1.24.1 and WikiEditor 0.4.0 and all defaults. The hosting service is DreamHost. Does anyone have a solution?  An older wiki I maintain uses MediaWiki version 1.19.11 and WikiEditor version 0.3.1 and the toolbar displays ok.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what git version or REL1_X version you're using? The version number was not updated, but there were massive code changes in last year (I sent a patch to update the number now).

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to tell for sure without information on what is displayed in your browser console or other logs (see [debugging](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:How_to_debug)).

However, a comment mention DreamHost: it may be a webserver-caused issue. One setting that often causes problems is the maximum allowed URL length; try setting [`$wgResourceLoaderMaxQueryLength = 512`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgResourceLoaderMaxQueryLength) or lower in your `LocalSettings.php`.